# Transferring domain from Ipage to Bluehost and want to keep old email

Tags: domains, email, domain-transfer, bluehost

I'm transferring two .com's that were originally setup on Ipage. I initiated the transfer on Bluehost for the domains to  and have created a email account with the same address as the email he wants to keep.

The domains transfer are still showing status of "Pending Domain.com, LLC Approval" and says can be up to 7 days. Once the transfers are complete, will the old email show up in the same email address account I created in bluehost or do I have to do something special to have his old email show up? I backed up his contacts in roundcube on his ipage and imported in roundcube on blue host but didn't see any where to export the email.

Answer (score 2):

You don't give any information about whether it is an IMAP account or a POP account.  The difference being that IMAP emails are stored on the server but generally POP emails are stored on a PC, though they *may* be retained on the server.

If it is a POP account and all emails are on the PC, all you need to do is create the email accounts at Bluehost (let's not get into a discussion about the problems with Bluehost).  Depending on the name of the mail server you are connecting to (`mail.example.com` compared to `mail.ipage.com`), the transition may be transparent.

For IMAP, the easiest way I have found is to compress the `/user/mail` and `/user/etc` directories and save them in the web facing home directory so you can either *wget* them directly or download them and then upload to the new host.

Once they are saved to the `/user/` directory on the new host, they should work with the same email address (username) and password and all the mail should be there.

The one drawback with this method is that if emails arrive after you move the accounts, and you don't do a follow up sync, they will be lost.

Comment: Hi, this is OP. For the original host/domain provider ipage.. I know the user only accessed it via webmail roundedcube. I don't know if it is imap or pop but I see setup directions for both? Also, I don't see that directory on his ipage ftp. Also, do I have to update the ipage MX info to now match what the bluehost mx info says? ipage has mx.siteurl.com and bluehost says mail.siteurl.com sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Hi Steve, have you been able to look at my previous comment?

Comment: If they are accessing it via roundcube, they are using IMAP protocol and all emails that haven't been removed from the deleted items folder will be there.  I can't be certain how ipage has their directory set up.   A standard cpanel/apache method is /user_home_directory/mail.  The MX record can be whatever you want e.g. mymxrecord.example.com, as long as you have a matching A record for it pointing to the IP address of the mail server.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to recheck his ftp but didn't see anything like that before. Question, the transfer from ipage to bluehost has been initiated as OP states but still "pending" since I'll have both the domain and hosting on bluehost do I need to do anything else after the transfer is complete in order to start seeing the emails go into bluehosts roundcube instead of ipage's as it still is now

Comment: Not if MX and email accounts are set up properly

Answer (score 0):

By "old email" I assume you mean his saved, old emails?  If so, the other poster is correct, you'll want to make a local backup of his email account, using an email client.  I know both Thunderbird and Outlook have a feature that does this.  It may also be called Export

If you just want him to be able to keep the email address he's been using, I don't believe there is really anything else you need to do.